# WordPress plugins not updating

Tags: wordpress, plugins, updates

I've looked at the other people on Stack overflow with updating issues, but my problems seems rather different from any of the others.

Unlike anyone else, I am not getting any sort of error message, or the website hanging, in fact at first glance it looks like everything worked fine. The update notification disappears and everything is as it should be. Until you realise none of the plugin version numbers have changed, and after 30 minutes or so the update notification will reappear.

[image]

This screen shot was taken an hour after updating all of the plugins with update notifications. As you can see the (6) next to the Menu item "Plugins" has reappeared indicating that there are 6 plugins which require updating.

Jetpack is one of those plugins. The update notification has not appeared next to the plugin itself, but the version number has remained the same. Updating it today, the version number should be 3.0.1

I'm totally baffled by this one. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What WP version are you using?

Comment: The latest one 3.9.1 the problem started sometime after version 3.8 it's been happening for awhile, but I thought it's gotten to the point now where it might start to become a serious issue.

Comment: Start turning off plugins one by one and test to see when some normal update functionality returns. When updates start working you'll know which plugin is the problem. If you end up with them all off and problem persists then I would suggest a re-install of the WP files onto your server. Replacing the files (backup your wpconfig) has sometimes fixed such problems.